# C# & Java Web Service Integration

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a C# application that should integrate with a Java application and the client recommends using web services.
So my C# Web service will be called from Java application.
What is the best option for me to use to maintain good data transformation between my C# web service and Client's Java application and also which one will let me send and receive complex data types:

1. Using ASP Web Services
2. Using WCF (BasicHttp Binding)
3. Using WCF (WebHttp Binding)

Comment: I'm a fan of WCF for *internal service integration* - *if* the client has a method of building the types based on the WSDL definition. "Web Services" have no such standard definition or schema format (which is great for JavaScript, eg, but not if you want a strongly-typed infrastructure without secondary type distribution). I would hope there are WCF-integration solutions for Java.

Answer (score 1):

WebHttpBinding (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Defines a binding element that is used to configure endpoints for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Web services that respond to HTTP requests instead of SOAP messages.

So this is more REST style http requests

BasicHttpBinding (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Represents a binding that a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service can use to configure and expose endpoints that are able to communicate with ASMX-based Web services and clients and other services that conform to the WS-I Basic Profile 1.1.

So it depends on what kind of services endpoints your C# service is exposing. If your going to expose REST style endpoints, use WebHttpBinding. Otherwise if you are exposing a SOAP protocol based webservices with an asmx endpoint then use option #1 or option #2

If you are exposing an .asmx endpoint then the wsdl should be normally available via a request like **`http://yourdomaine.com/serviceuri.asmx?wsdl`** (example :[here](http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL)). You can provide that wsdl to Apache CXF wsdl to java (see [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)). The description says:

> wsdl2java takes a WSDL document and generates fully annotated Java code from which to implement a service. The WSDL document must have a valid portType element, but it does not need to contain a binding element or a service element. Using the optional arguments you can customize the generated code. In addition, wsdl2java can generate an Ant based makefile to build your application.

See the link for the full list of options to use.

So, with the appropriate options it will generate the necessary java classes for data interchange (complex types) as well as service invocation classes which would be wrapped into your business services.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

here is a good example: [Example](http://geekswithblogs.net/ballhaus/archive/2009/12/28/net-wcf-and-java-ws-interoperability-part1.aspx)

it uses BasicHttpBinding